# How do you get the value of the JFrame title?

Tags: java, swing, title, getvalue

I want to be able to get the string from the `JFrame`. This is because the title of the `JFrame` is not constant and is dependent on variables.

Is there a way to assign to a string variable the text of the title?

```
    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if(super.checkifEmptyFields(jPanel3)==false){
        String LeaseName = jTextField2.getText().toLowerCase();
        String sld[]  =jDateChooser1.getDate().toString().split(" ");
        String startLeasingDate = sld[0]+","+sld[1]+","+sld[5].toLowerCase();
        String eld[]  =jDateChooser1.getDate().toString().split(" ");
        String EndLeasingDate = eld[0]+","+eld[1]+","+eld[5].toLowerCase();
        String leaseAmount = jTextField3.getText();
        String text = jTextField1.getText();
        int floor = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(6, 7));
        int flat = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(13));
        //String name NewLease2.getTitle;
    }
}
```

The class name is called NewLease2 and this is the function I want to perform when the user presses a button.

Comment: In the constructor of the `JFrame`, you could set a private instance variable and assign it the value of the title.

Comment: jframe.getTitle(), which is an inherited method from awt.frame

Comment: You can use well known setTittle and getTitle APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why dont you try:

```
JFrame j = new JFrame("My Title here");
String whatTitle = j.getTitle();
```

Comment: I had thought that this function exisited so I tried it but I cant seem to call the function .gettitle. Do you know any reasons why?

Comment: update your code and let me see how are you calling that Method....

Comment: This helped me in answering my specific problem. For anyone who had a similar problem, check mine below.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of the `JFrame`, you could set a private instance variable and assign it the value of the title.

This will store the original value for the title of your instance object.

```
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
    private String originalTitle;

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return this.originalTitle;
    }

    public MyJFrame() {
        super();

        this.originalTitle = this.getTitle(); // Store a snapshot of the title.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Thanks so much for your help Xoce 웃 Пepeúpa. I just said this in my function.

```
 private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    if(super.checkifEmptyFields(jPanel3)==false){
        String LeaseName = jTextField2.getText().toLowerCase();
        String sld[]  =jDateChooser1.getDate().toString().split(" ");
        String startLeasingDate = sld[0]+","+sld[1]+","+sld[5].toLowerCase();
        String eld[]  =jDateChooser1.getDate().toString().split(" ");
        String EndLeasingDate = eld[0]+","+eld[1]+","+eld[5].toLowerCase();
        String leaseAmount = jTextField3.getText();
        String text = jTextField1.getText();
        int floor = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(6, 7));
        int flat = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(13));
        JFrame j = this;
        String m =j.getTitle(); // << This is the bit that gets the title.
    }
```

And now it works :)